# synchronizing databases across two machines

Tags: database

I have a laptop and desktop development machine, I'm trying to always be in sync with both data in database and files.

I fixed my file issue by running unison scripts which works beautifully.
My issue is my database now. Is there any graceful way to handle that or do I need to dump and reinsert every time i want to refresh updates?
I'm using mysql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use database replication .. check the [Mysql Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)